# looping over columns in a 2d list

Tags: python, list, loops, nested, nested-loops

I am trying to loop over each column in this 2d list and count how many times the 'thing' or 'A' shows up in that column. This is what I am trying to do and here is the 2d list.

```
l =    [ ["A", 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5],
     ["A","A", 2 , 3 , 4 , 5],
     [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 5 ],
     ["A","A","A","A","A","A"],
     ["A", 3 ,"A", 4 ,"A","A"],
     [ 1 , 3 , 5 ,"A", 5 ,"A"] ]

col_count=[]
co = []
for i in l:
    co.append[0]
    for x in co:
        c = 0
        if thing == x:
            c += 1
    col_count.append(c)
print(col_count)
```

I am trying to get the first element of every row then add it to a list and go through it that way.

the expected output is

```
[4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [ ["A", 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5],
    ["A","A", 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ],
    [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 5 ],
    ["A","A","A","A","A","A"],
    ["A", 3 ,"A", 4 ,"A","A"],
    [ 1 , 3 , 5 ,"A", 5 ,"A"]]

col_count = []

for X in range(6):
    Count = 0
    for Y in range(len(l)):
        if l[Y][X] == "A":
            Count += 1
    col_count.append(Count)
print(col_count)
```

This should work, it loops through the columns and adds one if its "A"

Answer (score 0):

You can [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the matrix (2D list) with `zip` and count occurrences of "A" in each row through list comprehension.

```
l = [
    ["A", 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ],
    ["A","A", 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ],
    [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 5 ],
    ["A","A","A","A","A","A"],
    ["A", 3 ,"A", 4 ,"A","A"],
    [ 1 , 3 , 5 ,"A", 5 ,"A"]
]

print([row.count("A") for row in [*zip(*l)]])
```

This works for any row and column count as long as column count is consistent in each row.